# What do I pass to the switch-to-buffer argument in my .emacs file?

Tags: emacs, elisp, dot-emacs

I am getting an error in my .emacs file at the following line:

```
(switch-to-buffer *Completions*)
```

error: symbols value as variable is void

I did a `describe-function` on `switch-to-buffer` and found I CAN pass it a BUFFER (and another optional argument which I do not currently need). What am I doing wrong?

Just a few notes:
a. I also need two similar lines `(switch-to-buffer *grep*)` and `(switch-to-buffer *compilation*)` so the simple solution of using `(switch-to-completions)` won't solve all of my problems.
b. All of the buffers I require are already open, so I don't think that is the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
(switch-to-buffer "*Completions*")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a buffer name, as such:

```
(switch-to-buffer "*Help*")
```

From the docs:

> Select buffer BUFFER in the current window.
> BUFFER may be a buffer **or a buffer name**.

Answer (score 0):

The implication of what Dewayne said is that you can pass objects returned from things like `(buffer-list)` to functions, if you're trying to do things programmatically, and don't particularly want to deal with strings as an intermediary.